# Problema com query para filtrar diferentes campos numa mesma tabela SQL

Tags: sql, query

Tenho uma tabela com logs de uso do GSUITE e gostaria de filtrar algumas métricas uma delas é a que segue e que estou com problemas para realizar. (Sou iniciante em SQL)

Procuro as seguintes informações: Total de usuários distintos que enviaram pelo menos um email em intervalos de um mês em dados de um ano de uso + Total de usuários que criaram pelo menos um tipo de documento no drive para os mesmos intervalos de tempo de um mês para a mesma base de dados.

Tentei o seguinte, mas como preciso fazer join com outras tabelas e adiciono mais um join a query nao funciona e da timeout

````
    count(distinct u.user_profile_id) as user_google, 
    count(distinct u2.user_profile_id) as user_drive,

    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM u.date) as mes, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM u.date) as ano 
    from stinsights.user_usage as u 

     join stinsights.user_usage as u2  
    on u2.customer_id = u.customer_id 
    and EXTRACT(MONTH FROM u2.date) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM u.date)
    and EXTRACT(YEAR FROM u2.date) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM u.date)
    and (u2.drive_num_google_documents_created > 0 
    or u2.drive_num_google_spreadsheets_created > 0 
    or u2.drive_num_google_presentations_created > 0
    or u2.drive_num_google_forms_created > 0)


    where  u.customer_id = 'id_do_cliente' 
    and  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM u.gmail_last_interaction_time) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM u.date)
    group by mes, ano order by ano, mes;```
````

Comment: Publique as estruturas das tabelas , em tese um UNION pode resolver o problema , defina "enviar email" e "documento no drive".

Answer (score 0):

Notei alguns erros no seu código:

```
from stinsights.user_usage as u 

 join stinsights.user_usage as u2  o código aqui
```

Você está fazendo um from da tabela stinsights.user_usage e depois você está relacionando com ela mesma no join (eu deixaria escrito bem claro inner join), se você tentar cruzar mais alguma tabela provavelmente vai dar dados redundantes e poderá até dar o timeout.

Outra pratica boa é você usar os condicionais da tabela no Where e nos Ands do Where, e não no inner join, utilize apenas o que relaciona uma tabela a outra no inner join. Fora que faltou um select no inicio de sua consulta.

Exemplo:

```
SELECT 
count(distinct u.user_profile_id) as user_google, 
count(distinct u2.user_profile_id) as user_drive,
EXTRACT(MONTH FROM u.date) as mes, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM u.date) as ano 

from stinsights.user_usage as u 

where  u.customer_id = 'id_do_cliente' 
and (u2.drive_num_google_documents_created > 0 
     or u2.drive_num_google_spreadsheets_created > 0 
     or u2.drive_num_google_presentations_created > 0
     or u2.drive_num_google_forms_created > 0)
and EXTRACT(MONTH FROM u.gmail_last_interaction_time) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM u.date)

group by mes, ano 

order by ano, mes;
```

Exclui o que era desnecessário em seu código.